# Logo image in html

Tags: html, css

I try to put logo using html and css .. here is the code which i try

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assignment/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="responsive">

<div>
<a  title="Comp_logo" href="">
<img alt="logo"   src="Assignment/images/logo.png">
</a>

</div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

I use sublime text editor so after this when i open index file this is what i see
[image](http://oi58.tinypic.com/1zbz11v.jpg)

[sublime text](http://oi57.tinypic.com/99qsud.jpg)

Comment: The image has a broken link I guess. You are not linking the CSS file properly as well.

Comment: Check the image path. Maybe it's incorrect. Or the image is broken.

Comment: In other words, are the logo and the stylesheet in the same directory as the HTML file?

Comment: i think path is correct .. check update question as i post image of sublime text ..

Comment: What you are trying to do with <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assignment/css"> in href it is pointing folder.. Use proper css file path..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the image path is correct. For example, if your folder structure is:

```
|-Assignment
|----images
|--------logo.png
|----css
|----index.html
```

... then the path to your image should be `images/logo.png`.

Comment: @scorpio Correct. I just noticed your second screenshot, and that's exactly the problem. There are a few other ways you could reference the image, but in this particular case, the relative path will work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use absolute path for image and css if you want that image will be displayed in text editor like http://www.yourdomain.com/Assignment/images/logo.png